# AppDomain missing or depricated in Windows 10 IoT Core and UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

For an app for Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi2, I need to use a launcher app or StartUp-Task, which creates a shadow copy of my app and launches it. I need to use this approach to be able to substitute DLLs during runtime, without having a lock on the DLLs and without disrupting running services. That's needed as the device running it, would be remote somewhere out of reach, deployed at a client's site and I need my app to be running to service the device. After updating my DLLs, I would restart it and it would run with the new libraries, start the launcher as default app, which then starts my app.

Before Windows 10 and UWP the approach was to use System.AppDomain from mscorlib.dll in the .NET Framework to create a new AppDomain in a cached directory. The config, executables and DLLs would be copied to a cache directory and run from there. That leaves the original DLL available for substitution and doesn't put a lock on them. This was also a very useful technique used in IIS and webapps, which needed to run without interruptions even if the code needs updating. The open threats keep servicing open requests until these are done and new requests will be serviced using the new updated versions.

Now in Windows 10 System.AppDomain is not available anymore. I tried Windows.System.ProcessLauncher but encountered several issues with it. First I have to register the EXE in the registry to allow launching it. Then it tells me I can only run it from an app container. I didn't get it to work as of now. It's just a tedious and messy approach IMHO.

Now to my question: What would you use as an alternative to the described old approach on Windows 10 IoT Core? Does anyone have a small snippet of sample code to share? Or perhaps a link pointing in the right direction? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is not compatible with the Universal Windows Platform app model.

You will have to push an updated package of your app.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that seems to be the case. Bugger. Exchanging a single DLL would've been so much more convenient than pushing a whole new app package. Pushing an updated package also means that the app will be terminated and wouldn't be running anymore, which terminates my connection to the device and therefore my capability to do anything with it. Seems like I have to use the Azure IoT Suite to push new app packages. It's just so inconvenient, that they don't support this perfectly working method anymore. :(